# WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync vs. HttpClient.GetAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I'm still getting to know the various async features of .NET 4.5, and I've run into something interesting. Given the following in my MVC controller, I get different results when executing (1) and (2)

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var stuff = SomeExpensiveFunction();
    return View(stuff);
}
private byte[] SomeExpensiveFunction() {
    string url = "http://some-url.../";

    // (1)
    var wc = new WebClient();
    return wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url).Result;

    // (2)
    var hc = new HttpClient();
    return hc.GetAsync(url).Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
}
```

On the surface, they seem the same - both the `WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync` and `HttpClient.GetAsync` are `async` methods which return a `Task`. The `WebClient` version returns `Task<byte[]>` while the `HttpClient` version returns `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` which I have to dig the bytes out of, but I'm calling `.Result` either way, which I would expect to complete prior to leaving the function.

With (1), I get a yellow-screen with `An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time...`. With (2), everything works fine.

I can change the whole stack and use an `async` on the controller method itself and the `SomeExpensiveFunction`, and everything works fine. But I'm trying to figure out if there's something fundamentally wrong with (1) or with `WebClient` in general when working with MVC. Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: I know in this example I can use the synchronous versions of those calls since I'm not really doing anything asynchronously - this is just an example based on a larger codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've fallen foul of ASP.NET's SynchronizationContext. To make the WebClient example work, you should make the entire controller asynchronous.  Try this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync() {
    string url = "http://some-url.../";
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
        return View(await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url));
}
```

See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4 for a briefing on asynchronous controllers, and http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronousnet-client-libraries-for-your-http-api-and-awareness-of-async-await-s-bad-effects for an explanation of the deadlocking effect of the async/await pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but this could be due to improper use of Async methods. Perhaps you are seeing this behavior because you are not expected to use Async methods in synchronous fashion by calling Result.

Comment: I figured I'm doing something wrong there, but I'm doing the exact same thing with `HttpClient` without error. Maybe `WebClient` and `HttpClient` do their internal asynchronous stuff differently, even if in the end both of them return a `Task<>`.